# vba code to search entire workbook for a specific background color

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I'm currently working on a report project that has subreports and compilation reports all in an excel document. It has 45 sheets in total minus a 'dashboard'-like sheet, a validation checking sheet, and two ghost sheets.

All subreports have its own data validation in certain cells with conditional formatting that will make the cell become red (RGB 192,0,0) if the user puts a wrong data inside it.

The problem that I had is that the sum of 2 wrong data on the same sheet could make the data seems right. But it's not.

The only way I thought that can help me prevent this is to search on all the cells in the workbook if any one of them turned into that red. and I need the code to able to list down the sheets that had the cell(s) into the validation sheet automatically if possible. Thank you in advance.

### Update

The [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/14xAWOjGJGrmknwty2vRCVPixvNkK33md/view) I am working on

Comment: this is the file that im working on [link](https://drive.google.com/open?id=14xAWOjGJGrmknwty2vRCVPixvNkK33md)

Comment: Please show us what you've tried so far (in code)

Comment: in code, none actually. it's not that i didn't try though. the problem is I don't really know how should i do it and what do i really need to search for. i'm actually in medical field trying to improve our own system. so i'm really in short of help in real life.

Comment: If you are using data validation, how are you able to enter the wrong data in a cell?

Comment: @Davesexcel my data validation depends on the value of another cell. so if the user insert the data in the data validated cell first (without inserting the targeted cell), then the CF will be triggered.

Comment: Perhaps knock up a worksheet change event, store the old value, perform calculations, check the cell's colour then revert the cell back to the old value with a msgbox warning?

Comment: So it's a specific conditionally formatted background colour you're after?  Searching just the background colour won't return that otherwise I'd suggest using something like `Application.FindFormat.Interior.Color = 255:Set rng = Sheet1.Cells.Find(What:="*", SearchFormat:=True)`.  You'll need to search for  anything that meets the criteria in your condition.

Comment: What is the conditional format you're looking for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this is a good start:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Worksheets("Sheet1").UsedRange '<= Search all usedrange cell by cell
        If cell.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = RGB(192, 0, 0) Then
            Debug.Print cell.Address '<= if the cell has the color mentioned above will print it is address
        End If
    Next cell

End Sub
```

Comment: @Davesexcel there was an error in my code and no i fix it!

Comment: thanks! this works for me. i never knew about .UsedRange before this. im pretty sure i can work my way around after this. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can click search from menu or press Ctrl+F

in the input box for search; open the options

[image]

Click Format and make a format you want to search after that click search and excel will find that format

**EDIT**

**VBA Version for finding red color in conditional formatting**

You can use this function to find the conditional formatting coloring in your sheet, i have made it to look for red color in sheet "TOD302(Tadika)"

```
Sub findRed()

    Dim used_range As Range
    Dim i As Integer

    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    ActiveSheet.Name = "Search Result"

    Sheets("TOD302(Tadika)").Select
    Set used_range = ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    i = 1

    Sheets("Search Result").Range("A" & i).Value = "Row"
    Sheets("Search Result").Range("B" & i).Value = "Column"
    Sheets("Search Result").Range("C" & i).Value = "address"

    i = 2
    For Each r In used_range

        If (r.DisplayFormat.Interior.Color = 192) Then

            Sheets("Search Result").Range("A" & i).Value = r.Row
            Sheets("Search Result").Range("B" & i).Value = r.Column
            Sheets("Search Result").Range("C" & i).Value = r.Address()

            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next

End Sub
```

Comment: i already tried macro version of this but i can't seem to make it loop the entire selected range of the specific sheets that i want. furthermore this macro won't show any CF background.

Comment: I have edited the answer you can check the macro on your data.